# SQLAlchemy one-to-many relationship clarification

Tags: sqlalchemy

After reading the SQLAlchemy documentation, it's still unclear to me how one-to-many relationships are actually supposed to be specified. I'll break down the documentation and explain why I'm confused (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many):

> A one to many relationship places a foreign key on the child table
>   referencing the parent.

It looks like I am to place some `Column` attribute on the model that will be on the "many" side of the relationship.

> relationship() is then specified on the parent, as referencing a collection of items represented by the child:

This means that there is some attribute on the parent that specifies the model participating in the "many" side of the relationship.

This would make total sense to me if it weren't for that fact that there could be a situation where I want to define two one-to-many relationships with the same participants on both sides of the relationship.

How does SQLAlchemy know that the `ForeignKey` column on the "many" side of the relationship corresponds to the `relationship` attribute placed on the "one" side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A one-to-many relationship is set up like this:

```
class Group(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    users = relationship(lambda: User)

class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Group.id))
```

SQLAlchemy infers that you meant to use `parent_id` as the join condition for `users` based on the fact that it's the *only* foreign key linking the two tables.

In the case where you have circular relationships:

```
class Group(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))
    users = relationship(lambda: User)

class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Group.id))
    owned_groups = relationship(Group)
```

If you try this, it won't work because SQLAlchemy complains that it cannot infer what foreign key to use for each relationship. Instead, you have to tell it explicitly what to use:

```
class Group(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))
    users = relationship(lambda: User, foreign_keys=lambda: User.parent_id)

class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Group.id))
    owned_groups = relationship(Group, foreign_keys=Group.owner_id)
```

A more complete example with backrefs:

```
class Group(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))
    users = relationship(lambda: User, foreign_keys=lambda: User.parent_id, back_populates="parent")
    owner = relationship(lambda: User, foreign_keys=owner_id, back_populates="owned_groups")

class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Group.id))
    owned_groups = relationship(Group, foreign_keys=Group.owner_id, back_populates="owner")
    parent = relationship(Group, foreign_keys=parent_id, back_populates="users")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Seems like you've been answering most of my questions lately...I appreciate the help!

Comment: It's interesting to me that SQLAlchemy would get confused about your middle example, since there is still at most only one foreign key on each class. (You've helped to answer my immediate question, so I'll accept the answer as is, but I'm curious if you could elaborate on what exactly SQLAlchemy would be confused about.)

Comment: @wheresmycookie The reason that SQLAlchemy can't determine that is because it's not free to assume that all relationships are one-to-many. They can be many-to-one as well. I added an example with backrefs which should make this clear. On each side, there are actually two relationships that correspond to each of the two foreign keys. Imagine that you are SQLAlchemy. In the second example, how do you know that `owned_groups` isn't supposed to be the other side of the `users` relationship (and therefore use the `parent_id` foreign key)?